# How to stop validating a field if the dependant field is invalid? - Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation

I am trying to validate a field based on the validity of another field and cant seem to find the answer. Either I am so dumb at searching or its painfully obvious, but I am not able to find a satisfying answer so asking here.

I have a form where I create a `unit`. The `unit` belongs to a `block` and the `block` belongs to a `class`. In my form, I have fields to select a `class` then the `block` of that `class`. What I am tring to achive is validate the `block` and my rule looks like this.

```
"block_id" => 'required|integer|min:1|exists:blocks,id,class_id,'.$request->input('class_id'),
```

the `class_id` is being validated prior to this rule like so

```
"class_id" => 'required|integer|min:1|exists:classes,id',
```

what I am trying to achive is to stop validating the `block_id` if the `class_id` is not valid.

I am also fine with stoping the validation altogether if the `class_id` is not valid because I am already validating the fields from fron-end. and this is an extra layer of security. so I am not conserned about user experience (because a normal user will not post invalid data).

How can I achive this?

My first guess is to validate the `class_id` first like

```
$request->validate([
    "class_id" => 'required|integer|min:1|exists:classes,id'
]);
```

then carry out the remaining validation rules. But then I will have to validate request twise(don't know if it matters any way).

Is there a simple solution to this like `$request->validate($rules, halt on first failure = true)` kind of option?. My instincts says there should be one but I am unable to find it.

Thanks in advance :)

PS: I did ask this question a few weeks back but got no response so reposting to see if there really is an answer here

Comment: You may be interested to explore possibilities of achieving what you desire with after validation hook https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#after-validation-hook and/or conditionally adding rules https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#conditionally-adding-rules

Comment: "validating the fields from fron-end. and this is an extra layer of security" Never rely solely on frontend validation. Validation on server is a **must** as a good practice for keeping you data and application protected. Frontend validation must be used primarily for better user experience and saving network requests

Comment: yeah I am actually looking for the after-validation-hook's like behaviour but not actually. The thing is I am doing two validations at two levels now much like validating after validating, what i am interested in is a way to specify the condition based of the state (like valid or invalid; not value - like 1 or 2) of `class_id` so conditional validation is not what i want

Comment: @Donkarnash I am not relying on front-end validation, the fact I mentioned that is because whenever i am searching for this perticular use case of mine - i get comments like "its a bad user exerience to send only one validation result and you must validate everything at once and send all the result" my line implies that i already took care of user experience, so, sending only one result does not affect a normal user at all.

Answer (score 0):

The rule you are looking for is called [`bail`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-bail):

> Stop running validation rules after the first validation failure.

Comment: but there is a catch, the `bail` rule will only apply to that one field, eg: if `class_id` is invalid then the bail rule will stop further validation on `class_id` but `block_id` will still be validated and the invalid `class_id` will be passed to `block_id`'s `exist` rule assuming all other rules have been met on `block_id`.